# How do I fit the value of one v-model into another v-model?

Tags: vue.js

In this example, I'm trying to fit the value from `div id="message"` into textarea using the Vue v-model construct, but this not work

```
<template>
<div>
    <textarea v-model="text"></textarea>
</div>


 <div>
    <div id="message" v-model="text2">{{ comment.message }}</div>
      <button @click="update(text2);">
           Edit
      </button>
</div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
   data() {
     return {
     text: [],
     text2: null
                   }
        },

methods: {

/* not work */
update(text2) {
   this.text = text2;  
    }
}
<script>
```

How do I make sure that when I click on the "edit" button, the value of `v-model="text2"` insert into `v-model="text"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `v-model` on a `<div>` because it isn't an input element.

It seems what you want to do is set `text` to the comment message when you click the edit button so that it can be edited by the textarea. All you have to do is pass `comment.message` as the argument:

```vue
<button @click="update(comment.message)">
```

A couple of other things:

1. You cannot have multiple root elements in your template (you have two root `<div>` elements). You can just wrap everything in a single `<div>`.
2. `text` has initial value `[]` which isn't compatible with a textarea's `v-model`; did you mean `''`?